# Cisco CCE: REST Update Request ErrorMessage: The specified URL does not exist

Tags: cisco

When i try to update agent skillgroup by REST Request i'm getting the following response:

```
        <apiError>
        <errorDetail xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="resourceErrorDetail">
            <refURL>https://x/unifiedconfig/config/agent/(id)</refURL>
            <apiErrors>
                <apiError>
                    <errorMessage>The specified URL does not exist.</errorMessage>
                    <errorType>notFound.dbData</errorType>
                </apiError>
            </apiErrors>
        </errorDetail>
        <errorMessage>There were one or more errors processing the following request: update https://x/unifiedconfig/config/agent/(id)</errorMessage>
        <errorType>operation.resourceErrors</errorType>
    </apiError>
```

What i already tooked care:

- Names and params all by documentaion
- Authorization seccess
- I'm getting info but cant update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Authorization, for update Agent Skillgroup the credential need to be Supervisor of the team you want access to.

Same authorization need to see the following API:

> https://{ServerIP}/unifiedconfig/config/skillgroup/

If you can see all skillgroup you would also change agent's skillgroup.

I also mention the syntax:

```
<operation>
<operationType>update</operationType>
<refURLs>
<refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5000</refURL>
<refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5001</refURL>
</refURLs>
<changeSet>
<agent>
<skillGroupsAdded>
<skillGroup>
<refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/skillgroup/6000</refURL>
</skillGroup>
</skillGroupsAdded>
<skillGroupsRemoved>
<skillGroup>
<refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/skillgroup/6001</refURL>
</skillGroup>
</skillGroupsAdded>
</changeSet>
</operation>
```